# sscanf in code composer studio read 0 instead of value

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "12";
    int  ex   = 0;
    int  timerClkSource = 0;
    ex = sscanf( str, "%d", &timerClkSource );
    printf("returnval %d, timerClkSource %d",ex,timerClkSource);
}
```

I expected the above code to return 12 but its returning 0. Returncode is 0 as expected.I am compiling code for msp430 micro controller using ccs ide. msp430 is 16 bit micro controller.Is it expected?I am using code composer studio ide.If it is not expected where is the issue?
Note: It is returning 12 in Precision32 IDE but its returning none in MSP430 v 5.5.0.00077

Comment: gcc gives a warning `warning: format '%d' expects type 'int *', but argument 3 has type 'int16_t *'`. That might well be the issue. (gcc still reports `12`, the expected answer.)

Comment: Yes, you're probably trying to stuff a 32 bit integer into a 16 bit space. If you make timerClkSource an int (int32_t), does it get the correct value? Note that you may have a similar problem with the printf, where it might expect a full 32 bit int for the %d code.

Comment: Changing the scanf format to `"%hd"` clears the error message as well.

Comment: %hd or changing to int32_t doesn't work it is behaving same.

Comment: The scanf() function would return the number of parameters it actually filled.  Since it is returning 0, no parameters were filled.  Also, replacing the scanf() line with ex = atof(str);  will perform the operation correctly

Comment: Still having an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function expects a 32 bit integer, although it's a 16 architecture.

It's also  might be a big endian CPU. So it may return 12 but the byte order will be:

```
00 00 00 0C
```

So you'll get a zero when accessing the lower 16 bits.

Comment: Even the below code behaves the same way.

    int main()
    {
        char str[] = "90";
        int  ex   = 0;
        int32_t timerClkSource = 0x12345678;
        ex = sscanf( str, "%d", &timerClkSource );
        printf("returnval %d, timerClkSource 0x%lx",ex,timerClkSource);
    }

Output: 
timerClkSource = 0x12345678
returnval = 0

Comment: Try with `"%i"`. I had trouble with `"%d"` in the distant past.

Comment: is this anything related to memory model? because it works well with 32 bit architechture in Precision32 IDE but not in 16bit architechture(MSP430 uC)in CCS

Comment: That's my guess. It could be a bug in the C standard library you have.